# matplotlib pyplot - subplots with sizes proportional to the data

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want to create a figure with subplots where the size of each subplot is proportional to the data it contains. For example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
data_dict = {'foo': (10,7,5), 'bar': (2,6,3), 'baz': (22,17,12)}
figure, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)
i = 0
for x in ['foo','bar','baz']:
    venn2(subsets = data_dict[x], set_labels=('A', 'B'), ax=axes[i])
    i += 1
```

I want to scale the size of each subplot by the sum of numbers in each Venn diagram (A+B+intersect). How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm new to drawing venn diagrams in matplotlib, but I think it's possible if you set the width ratio in gridspec_kw. I sum up the data from the dictionary data, determine the composition ratio, and specify that as the ratio.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2

data_dict = {'foo': (10,7,5), 'bar': (2,6,3), 'baz': (22,17,12)}
ratios = [sum(v) for v in data_dict.values()]
norm = [n / sum(ratios) for n in ratios]

figure, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=norm))
i = 0
for x in ['foo','bar','baz']:
    venn2(subsets = data_dict[x], set_labels=('A', 'B'), ax=axes[i])
    i += 1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How about if the subplots grid is e.g. 2x2 ?

Comment: With 2x2, you can do this by setting both the height and width. For example, the following. `plt.subplots(2, 2, gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[1,1], height_ratios=[2,1])`